# How to use lucene across multiple websites

Tags: architecture, lucene

I've got four websites that are edited via one CMS (hanging off one of the sites) like this:

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
www.domain3.com
www.domain4.com
www.domain4.com/cms
```

I'll be using Lucene to index the textual content (from database and uploaded documents) of all four sites. The index will have to be available to both the CMS system, and the search page on each domain / website (which may be on different physical servers).

So should I use one lucene index on the domain that hosts the CMS system, or put an index on each domain? (I'm guessing I'll have to write some sort of web service to tie everything together for either solution). Is there a recommended method for achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible reasons for using separate indexes are having distinct content on each domain, where you do not wish to find search matches from the other domains, or a scalability issue. Otherwise it seems better to use a single search server having clients on four domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm planning something very similar to this....

What i'll probably do is have a single lucene index, with a "service" (web service, or wcf) above it, to query the index, and update the index. 
think of it as a seperate domain that handles searching

Comment: This was the direction I was thinking of too, seems less hassle than telling the CMS which lucene index it should be updating every time

Answer (score 2):

How about running Lucene as a stand-alone server shared by these clients?  Check out [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Answer (score 1):

We have had some success with simple placing the lucene index on a file share that is accessible by all servers. This isn't really supported but works perfectly for our needs. This is a relatively low traffic scenario though.

If your index is only updated from one of the sites then you can simply copy it across to the other servers after each update. Or on a hourly/daily basis.